# Principled Shader and Fresnel - Geometry or Normals?

Tags: shaders

The Principled Shader (PS) correctly applies Fresnel all the time.  Brilliant!  But is it based on geometry or on normals?  If I have a high-poly figure with many facets smoothly curving away from the camera, I get the correct Fresnel at the point facing the camera and the point orthogonal to the camera, and all points in between, right?  What if I use that high-poly to bake a normal map for a low-poly version?  The geometry won't have much of a continuum of angles, but the normals will.

I think the answer is normals -- the Shade Smooth operation is just interpolating normals and I'm certain the Fresnel is calculated correctly.  Can anyone confirm how this works?  Or if there is a cutoff, perhaps, where you need to have a minimum amount of geometry for the Fresnel to work with the PS?

Comment: In case this question is left unanswered by a blender developer: I can't see any indication of that it only uses the geometry only. I can see indications that it uses the normal map.  But I can't answer with 100% certainty.

Comment: Yup, that's where I'm coming from.  Sorta kinda think I know what the answer is, but it would be nice to have a definitive answer (that might reveal some useful insights along the way).